# vestacp error ssl intermediate chain is not valid

Tags: ssl, vestacp

I am facing issue at vestacp: during pass the 
SSL Certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
b5XsfsteyPAX9uLwiTctWC4TO9UsnjWKx2ZBt8q4WgQ5nrmkXUwv
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

SSL Key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
OOTW0NwF+ENrko9JHyLGZPOrk1w/+DElPHYZWMRXB/SJIsvehu/lgMpEEGgT
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

i have already checked my certificate result this link: https://decoder.link/
it show me my certificate is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. In the SSL Certificate field:

Paste the contents of the certificate issued to your domain. In windows you can usually verify this by simply double clicking (or opening) the .crt file. A window will pop-up with information about the certificate. Just check under "Issued to:" and make sure its issued to your domain.

2. In the SSL Key field

Paste the contents of the key that was created during the generation of the csr. It usually begins with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

3. In the SSL Certificate Authority/Intermediate

Paste the contents of the CA bundle certificate you received from your CA. That is the certificate without your domain name under "Issued to:" as explained in step 1.

Hope this helps someone. You can also read https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/ to understand certificate chains.